# Value of type 'SSBadgeButton' has no member 'animationZoom'

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I have following productviewcontroller which says "Value of type 'SSBadgeButton' has no member 'animationZoom'" -

```
 import UIKit

 class ProductViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,
                         UITableViewDelegate {
let notificationButton = SSBadgeButton()
let rightbarbuttonimage = UIImage(named:"ic_cart")
fileprivate var cart = Cart()
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let sections = ["Section A", "Section B","Section C", "Section D","Section   E","Section F","Section G","Section H", "Section I","Section J","Section K","Section L"]
let rowspersection = [2,3,1,2,2,3,3,1,4,2,1,2]


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    
    //Add and setup scroll view
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    
    //Constrain scroll view
    self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true;
    self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true;
    
    // customising rightBarButtonItems as notificationbutton
    notificationButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
    notificationButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_cart")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    notificationButton.badgeEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: notificationButton)
    
    
    
    //following register is needed because I have rightbarbuttonitem customised as   uibutton i.e.  notificationbutton
    notificationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.registerTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
@objc func registerTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCart", sender: nil)
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    
    
    
    //Workaround to avoid the fadout the right bar button item
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    
    //Update cart if some items quantity is equal to 0 and reload the product table and right button bar item
    cart.updateCart()
    
    
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Checkout (\(cart.items.count))"
    notificationButton.badge = String(cart.items.count)// making badge equal to no.ofitems in cart
    
    tableView.reloadData()
}

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// this segue to transfer data
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showCart" {
        if let cartViewController = segue.destination as? CartViewController {
            cartViewController.cart = self.cart
        }
    }
    }

   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return productMap.count
}
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return productMap[section]?.count ?? 0
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let product = productMap[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    cell.imageView?.image =  product.imagename
    cell.delegate = self as CartDelegate
    cell.setButton(state: self.cart.contains(product: product))
    return cell
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    
    switch(section) {
    case 0: return "Section A"
    case 1: return "Section B"
    case 2: return "Section C"
    case 3: return "Section D"
    case 4: return "Section E"
    case 5: return "Section F"
    case 6: return "Section G"
    case 7: return "Section H"
    case 8: return "Section I"
    case 9: return "Section J"
    case 10: return "Section K"
    case 11: return "Section L"
    default: return ""
    }
      }
  }



  extension ProductViewController: CartDelegate {

// MARK: - CartDelegate
func updateCart(cell: ProductTableViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    let product = productMap[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]
    
   var selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        if let index = selectedIndexPaths.firstIndex(of: indexPath) {
            selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
            removeProductFromCart(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    } else {
        selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        addProductToCart(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
     addProductToCart(indexPath: indexPath)
    
    //Update Cart with product
    cart.updateCart(with: product)
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Checkout (\(cart.items.count))"
   notificationButton.badge = String(cart.items.count) // making badge equal to  noofitems in cart
    
   }


    func addProductToCart(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProductTableViewCell {
    if let imageView = cell.imagename {
        
        let initialImageViewFrame = imageView.convert(imageView.frame, to: self.view)
        let targetImageViewFrame = self.notificationButton.frame
        
        let imgViewTemp = UIImageView(frame: initialImageViewFrame)
        imgViewTemp.clipsToBounds = true
        imgViewTemp.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imgViewTemp.image = imageView.image
        
        self.view.addSubview(imgViewTemp)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            imgViewTemp.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        }) {  _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                imgViewTemp.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.2, y: 0.2).rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                imgViewTemp.frame = targetImageViewFrame
            }) { _ in
                imgViewTemp.removeFromSuperview()

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
                    self.notificationButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)
                }, completion: {_ in
                    self.notificationButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                })
            }
             }
            }
           }
         }

     func removeProductFromCart(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ProductTableViewCell {
    if let imageView = cell.imagename {
        
        let initialImageViewFrame = self.notificationButton.frame
        let targetImageViewFrame = imageView.convert(imageView.frame, to: self.view)
        
        let imgViewTemp = UIImageView(frame: initialImageViewFrame)
        imgViewTemp.clipsToBounds = true
        imgViewTemp.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imgViewTemp.image = imageView.image
        
        self.view.addSubview(imgViewTemp)
        
        var initialTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        initialTransform = initialTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
        initialTransform = initialTransform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.notificationButton.animationZoom(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4) ***//Error - Value of type 'SSBadgeButton' has no member 'animationZoom'***
            imgViewTemp.transform = initialTransform
        }) {  _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.notificationButton.animationZoom(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                imgViewTemp.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                imgViewTemp.frame = targetImageViewFrame
            }) { _ in
                imgViewTemp.removeFromSuperview()
            }
           }
         }
      }
  }
    
   }
```

This is my code for "SSBadgeButton" -

```
 import UIKit

 class SSBadgeButton: UIButton {

  var badgeLabel = UILabel()

  var badge: String? {
didSet {
    addBadgeToButon(badge: badge)
    }
    }

    public var badgeBackgroundColor = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
    badgeLabel.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
     }
  }

    public var badgeTextColor = UIColor.white {
     didSet {
    badgeLabel.textColor = badgeTextColor
    }
    }

    public var badgeFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0) {
    didSet {
    badgeLabel.font = badgeFont
     }
  }

  public var badgeEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets? {
    didSet {
      addBadgeToButon(badge: badge)
    }
   }

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
   super.init(frame: frame)
     addBadgeToButon(badge: nil)
   }

 func addBadgeToButon(badge: String?) {
badgeLabel.text = badge
badgeLabel.textColor = badgeTextColor
badgeLabel.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
badgeLabel.font = badgeFont
badgeLabel.sizeToFit()
badgeLabel.textAlignment = .center
let badgeSize = badgeLabel.frame.size

let height = max(18, Double(badgeSize.height) + 5.0)
let width = max(height, Double(badgeSize.width) + 10.0)

var vertical: Double?, horizontal: Double?
if let badgeInset = self.badgeEdgeInsets {
    vertical = Double(badgeInset.top) - Double(badgeInset.bottom)
    horizontal = Double(badgeInset.left) - Double(badgeInset.right)
    
    let x = (Double(bounds.size.width) - 10 + horizontal!)
    let y = -(Double(badgeSize.height) / 2) - 10 + vertical!
    badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
} else {
    let x = self.frame.width - CGFloat((width / 2.0))
    let y = CGFloat(-(height / 2.0))
    badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))
   }

badgeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = badgeLabel.frame.height/2
badgeLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
addSubview(badgeLabel)
badgeLabel.isHidden = badge != nil ? false : true
  }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
self.addBadgeToButon(badge: nil)
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
   }
```

Earlier, it used to work fine. It used to zoom the animation Now, I don't know why it does not  work fine ? please help me with this. The code also seems okay. still, it does not work fine.